# Parse JSON API Call with HTTParty in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, httparty

I am trying to get the share count from this Linkedin API call using HTTParty in Rails, but it doesn't seems to properly be parsing and obtaining data. Why is that?

```
count = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get('https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' + url + '&format=json')["count"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`body` attribute](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httparty/0.13.0/frames) instead of the return value of the `get` (`HTTParty::Response`).

```
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' + url + '&format=json'
count = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get(url).body)["count"]
#                                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: @user2270029, What is the value of the `url`?

Comment: It worked when I restarted my rails server. Thanks for your help.